# Change data form Table to Array

Tags: list-manipulation

Ok, I am trying to figure out how exactly to change the data from `Table` such as

```
ptopp = Transpose[{pressure[[All, 1]], pressure[[All, 2]]}]
(* {{0., 59.5}, {0.1, 30.7}, {0.2, 
  21.1}, {0.3, -7.73}, {0.4, -17.3}, {1., -36.6}, {5., -75.}, {8., \
-104.}, {10., -123.}, {15., -94.2}, {20., -65.4}, {35., -36.6}, {65., \
-7.73}, {100., 1.87}} *)
```

into an `Array`. And I want to do that because I have to fit some function to that and I think it might be the best idea to use `ListInterpolation` which requires `Array`. There is something written about including the x component into the `Array` here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListInterpolation.html but I don't really understand how to convert it from a table to the desired form. Could semobody help?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to `ListInterpolation` can either be a range of x-values (assumed to be equally spaced) *or* a list of x-values corresponding to the list values. So in your case you may simply do

```
ListInterpolation[ pressure[[All,2]] , pressure[[All,1]] ]
```

Or simply use

```
Interpolation[ptopp]
```

for the same result, or

```
InterpolatingPolynomial[ptopp,x]
```

if you want a polynomial instead of an `InterpolatingFunction`